# Magento 2 remove catergory block-vertnav

Tags: magento, magento2

I want to remove the category navigation on the left of the screen. When ik look in the source I see that the block is named:

```
<div class="block block-vertnav clearfix hide-below-768">
```

How do I disable this block with an XML update?

Answer (score 0):

There are two way to remove the category navigation see below:

**Way 1:**

Add this to your theme `default.xml`

```
<referenceBlock name="catalog.leftnav" remove="true" />
```

OR

**Way 2:**

Add this on `Admin Panel > Products > Categories > YOUR PAGE > Design`

```
<referenceContainer name="catalog.leftnav" remove="true" />
```